# Sorting List randomly by weights

Tags: c#, sorting, random, statistics, probability

The idea is that i have a list of items with each item having a weight attached. Now i want to randomize the order of the list, but i also want to take the weight into account to "bias" the randomization process.

There are multiple approaches for that, but i'm particulary interested in one certain approach and why it is producing different distribution than i expect. The code is probably fine, but i want to get understanding, why it does what it does?

I know other algorithms that produce expected result.

One is to basically create a range, each with the length of particular item's weight and then randomly pick a point from the full range that got produced. This creates item one-by-one, by doing that over and over again until there are no items/no range to pick from. It produces the expected ratios over a million tries.

There's also another algorithm, that doesn't need range to be produced, but expects initial list to be in random order and then through substraction and checking against x <= 0, also takes items one-by-one to produce a list of randomly, but biased order of items. It produces the expected ratios over a million tries.

The approach i want to currently concentrate on, is to produce a ordering value for each item, and then order the whole list in one go. The code i have written does not produce expected ratios over a million tries.

C# code for a console application

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Name = "A70", Weight = 70},
                new Item { Name = "B20", Weight = 20},
                new Item { Name = "C10", Weight = 10},
            };

            var stats = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            myList.ForEach(x => stats.Add(x.Name, 0));

            var rnd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            {
                var newList = GetSorted(myList, rnd);
                ++stats[newList.First().Name];
            }

            var sum = stats.ToList().Sum(x => x.Value);
            stats.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key}: {((float)x.Value / sum * 100):0.00}%"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Item> GetSorted(IEnumerable<Item> list, Random rnd)
        {
            return list
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Order = x.Weight * rnd.NextDouble(),
                    Item = x
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Order)
                .Select(x => x.Item);
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

By this code, i would expect probability of each item to be in the first position of the list to be very similar to the weights of each item. Instead of 70-20-10% ratio, i get roughly 85-13-2% ratios. It almost looks like there's some kind of non-linearity coming into play, but i just don't get it right now.

The question here is to understand, how this given code works. I know and have different approaches that work and produces expected result.

Thank you!

Comment: You are getting the same random number every time.  You need to use the Next() method : var newList = GetSorted(myList, rnd.Next());

Comment: Not really. I'm not passing random value, but Random object and call rnd.NextDouble() in the GetSorted() method. If it would be constant, i would get 100% of the highest weighted item, and 0% on everything other.

Comment: You are getting an overlap.  So your ranges are 1) 0 to 70 2) 0 to 20 3) 0 to 10 The 3 probabilities are something like One) 1/3 (0 to 10) + 1/2 (11 to 20) + (20 to 70) Two) 1/3 ( 0 to 10) + 1/2 (10 to 20) Three) 1/3(0 to 10)

Comment: Thank you!
I get the logic. Though results doesn't completely confirm this. In current case, the 0-10 range would happen with probability 10/70, and then a third element is happening 1/3 of the time of it. 10/70/3 = ~4,8%. I get about half of it...

Comment: If you just look at the last case it is 10/3 ~ 2.  I can calculate the exact wrong results if necessary.  I've taken enough college level course to do it.

Comment: The total range is 70, not 100, isn't it? 10/3 is also well over 3, not even close to 2. And i have never questioned your time spent in education system. Why so hostile?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be hostile.  Just was lazy to do the precise calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation. For simplicity lets consider a simpler case:

```
var myList = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Name = "A20", Weight = 20},
    new Item { Name = "B10", Weight = 10},
};
```

We are determining the sort order by multiplying Weight with a random number. If we multiply the weight of A20 with any number above 0.5, will be sorted first whatever the random number for B10 is. If we multiply the weight of A20 with any number bellow 0.5, then it has an equal chance with B10 to by the first. So the distribution will be 75%/25%, and not the initially intuitive 67%/33%.

To fix the algorithm you must use the square root of the Weight.

```
.Select(x => new
{
    Order = Math.Sqrt(x.Weight) * rnd.NextDouble(),
    Item = x
})
```

---

**Update:** Squaring the weights is not a good fix.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It does give some insight to it! Though the given solution doesn't really solve it, the ratios are still off. A 90/10 probability becomes 83/17 consistently for example.

Comment: @GigAHerZ you are right! I updated my answer to reflect that my fix is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed code to work :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var myList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { Name = "A70", Weight = 70},
                new Item { Name = "B20", Weight = 90},
                new Item { Name = "C10", Weight = 100},
            };

            var stats = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            myList.ForEach(x => stats.Add(x.Name, 0));

            var rnd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
            {
                var newList = GetSorted(myList, rnd);
                ++stats[newList.Name];
            }

            var sum = stats.ToList().Sum(x => x.Value);
            stats.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: '{1}", x.Key, ((float)x.Value / sum * 100)));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        private static Item GetSorted(List<Item> list, Random rnd)
        {
            Item results = null;
            int value = rnd.Next(0,100);
            for(int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (value < list[i].Weight)
                {
                    results = list[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a fix. It's a different algorithm that i have described in original post. I already know it works and produces correct results. It was never a question of finding a working solution...

EDIT: Even worse, it doesn't even produce a list of items, but just picks one item. Completely off topic answer.

Comment: It is your algorithm exactly : One is to basically create a range, each with the length of particular item's weight and then randomly pick a point from the full range that got produced.   Your code only took first item and not an array.

Comment: Please read the original post. I have written: "The question here is to understand, how this given code works. I know and have different approaches that work and produces expected result."

Your code represents nothing like the given code algorithmically...

Comment: My code produces range, each with the length of particular item's weight .  I'm just using the upper end of the range.  Range 1 : 0 to 69, Range 2 :70 to 89, Range 3 : 90 to 99.  The three ranges are 70, 20, 10 which are the weights.